# iOS: Implementing UITabBar from User Interface without a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar, ibaction, iboutlet

In my app I have a UIViewController to which I wish to add a UITabBar. So I have added it via User Interface (into the UIViewController.xib file) and created instances of the IUTabBar and the UITabBarItems within the UIViewController.h+m files. in the xib file I was able to connect the code items to the ones on the xib (by dragging from the File Owner to the relevant item and selecting the relevant IBOutlet) but I cannot seem to connect back the buttons to the IBActions written on the h+m files.

Before adding the UITabBar I worked with a UIToolBar and had no problem doing these connections.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should implement the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol ([documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).

Once you are implementing this protocol, just use the `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method to know when a user changes the selected item of a tab bar.  In this method's implementation, you will have to check which item is selected, and manually change your view's content based on that.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have some clarifications:

Comment: 1. When you say "You should implement the UITabBarDelegate protocol" you mean to add to my UIViewController.h file the UITabBarDelegate inheritance? like this: @interface HowDoButtonsView : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>

Comment: 2. How exactly am I supposed to use the method "- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)..."? am I supposed to have it someplace within another method in my code or to call it using "IBAction"?

Answer (score 1):

// Disable this

```
UITabBarController.tabbar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

// Enable this

```
UITabBarController.tabbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```